# How can I change the highlight color in Illustrator's pattern editing mode?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, highlights

Somehow the highlight color in **Pattern Editing Mode** has been set to yellow for me.

I'm having considerable difficulty seeing selections unless I place some random dark-filled object behind everything... then toggle it visible/hidden so I can double check the work.

I can't, for the life of me, find *anywhere* to designate the Pattern Editing **highlight color**.

The *layer* highlight in the layers panel is set to Medium Blue.

[image]

But this seems to have *no bearing* in Pattern Editing Mode, I get yellow...

[image]

I can find **nowhere** to change the Pattern Editing highlight color.

Searching the web only finds content related to "how to change pattern colors" and not the application's *highlight* color.

So... **How on Earth does a user change the highlight color used in Illustrator's Pattern Editing Mode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR:

**Pattern Editing Mode** uses the *next* layer highlight color in the Layer Highlight color list, as if Pattern Editing were a "layer" and not actually a "mode."

**Illustrator CS6** has a bug and the application uses an internal list which is **different** than the list displayed to users, see below. The bug *may* also be present in CC versions.

---

---

---

***Please bear with me***... it takes some explaining of Layer Highlight functionality in case one's not familiar with it. In addition, there are app inconsistencies (i.e. bugs) which *may* be present depending upon the version of AI is use.

Some of the issues **may** be resolved in newer versions of Illustrator, I don't know. 
For anyone using legacy versions, be warned.... **it can be tricky**.

---

Look at the **Layer** highlight color list by double-clicking a layer thumbnail in the **Layers Panel**....

[image]

The *order* of these colors matters (<sup>*</sup>most of the time).

When you add a new **Layer** the next color down is designated as that new layer's *highlight* color.

New files start with Layer 1 set to `Light Blue`... so if a Layer is added, Layer 2 will be set to `Light Red`...

[image]

This continues down the list for *layers* - Layer 3 will have `Green` set highlights...

[image]

.... Layer 4 `Medium Blue`, etc.....

---

### <sup>*</sup>The "broken" part in some versions of Illustrator...

Some versions of Illustrator **don't** adhere to the list order at all times.

For example **Illustrator CS6** will skip `Magenta` and `Cyan`, jump straight to `Yellow`, *then* go *back* to `Magenta`, then `Cyan`. So for CS6 the app actually uses a variation of what is displayed to the user.

##### Illustrator CS6's *actual* list order:

Light Blue
Light Red
Green
Medium Blue
Yellow
Magenta
Cyan
Light Grey
Black
...etc.

I do not know why Yellow comes before Magenta when the app auto-assigns layer highlight colors. It appears to be a bug in CS6 to me. It may or may *not* be different in *any* version of AI.

<sub>(A user can *manually* change the **layer** highlight color by picking a color from the list. If a *different* highlight color, other than the default, is chosen the list *starts over* from the user-assigned color. If Layer 3 is set by the user to `Light Blue` for the highlight color, the list starts over... Layer 4 will then use `Light Red`, Layer 5 `Green`, etc. )</sub>

---

### The Tricky Part for Pattern Editing Mode

**Pattern Editing Mode** uses the ***next*** color in the list as if it were a "layer" and not a "mode"

What this means is..

For example using Illustrator CS6 (and noting the bug/list above)... if the **Layer** highlight color is set to `Medium Blue`... looking at the (actual) list above, `Yellow` will be the *next* color. So when entering Pattern Editing Mode, `Yellow` is used as the highlight color.

[image]

This is also seen when a new Layer is added.. the highlight for the *next layer* is `Yellow`:

[image]

---

So...

**To change the Pattern Editing Highlight Color**, change the highlight color assigned to the **top Layer in the Layers Panel**. Assign the color **before** the color you *actually* want.

If you want the Pattern Editing Highlight to be `Green`, assign `Light Red` as the *highlight* color for the top layer in the **Layers Panel**.

---

I did warn you it's a tad tricky.

I can't really explain the Adobe logic behind all of this.